# React, this is undefined in render() and in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am iterating over an array of string with all of my routes. Then checking to see if the current window.location.href` contains any of those routes, if it does, then I am getting the matching ref and adding a class to change the css.

I tried this method in `componentDidMount()` and in `render()` prior to the return statement. React keeps telling me that `this` is undefined.

## react/src/pages/nav.js

```
      render() {
        let allRoutes = [];
        this.props.route.childRoutes.forEach(route => {
          allRoutes.push(route.path)
        })
        const url = window.location.href;
        allRoutes.forEach(route => {
          if (url.includes(route)) {
            this.refs[route].classList.add('active')
          } else {
            this.refs.root.classList.add('active')
          }
        })
```

## console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/bundle.self-952529963c9d96b227c46b5e763e815b470d4de62fa7b9b876d16aa3475efce8.js?body=1:3270:2), <anonymous>:50:29)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Nav.render (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/bundle.self-952529963c9d96b227c46b5e763e815b470d4de62fa7b9b876d16aa3475efce8.js?body=1:3270:2), <anonymous>:48:17)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/bundle.self-952529963c9d96b227c46b5e763e815b470d4de62fa7b9b876d16aa3475efce8.js?body=1:2538:2), <anonymous>:796:21)
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/bundle.self-952529963c9d96b227c46b5e763e815b470d4de62fa7b9b876d16aa3475efce8.js?body=1:2538:2), <anonymous>:75:12)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/bundle.self-952529963c9d96b227c46b5e763e815b470d4de62fa7b9b876d16aa3475efce8.js?body=1:2538:2), <anonymous>:795:25)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/bundle.self-952529963c9d96b227c46b5e763e815b470d4de62fa7b9b876d16aa3475efce8.js?body=1:2538:2), <anonymous>:822:32)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/bundle.self-952529963c9d96b227c46b5e763e815b470d4de62fa7b9b876d16aa3475efce8.js?body=1:2538:2), <anonymous>:362:30)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/bundle.self-952529963c9d96b227c46b5e763e815b470d4de62fa7b9b876d16aa3475efce8.js?body=1:2538:2), <anonymous>:258:21)
    at Object.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/bundle.self-952529963c9d96b227c46b5e763e815b470d4de62fa7b9b876d16aa3475efce8.js?body=1:2178:2), <anonymous>:46:35)
```

If I place a debugger in the conditional

```
allRoutes.forEach(route => {
  if (url.includes(route)) {
    debugger
```

and check `this` in the console, it returns `undefined`

Comment: You should try `let _this = this;`

Comment: Please include the full error along with stack trace.

Comment: One of the benefits of using arrow functions is lexical binding of `this` so we don't need to resort to that  `_this = this` trick. What made it neccessary in your case?

Comment: That's not possible. If `_this` was `undefined`, `this` must be `undefined` as well, in which case accessing `this.props` would have already thrown an error.

Comment: @FelixKling well https://babeljs.io/repl/#?code=const%20render%20%253D%20()%20%253D%3E%20%7B%20const%20_this%20%253D%20this%253B%20console.log(%20_this%20)%20%7D

Comment: @pawel: That seems to confirm what I said? In your example `this` is `undefined`. If you had tried to access something like `this.props`, just as the OP did, you would get an error similar to "cannot read property 'props' of `undefined`. It would not even get to the point of evaluate `_this`.

Comment: I only included `const _this = this` because I received the error of `this is undefined`. If I put a debugger in the `forEach` loop and enter `this` in the console, it returns undefined. `_this` was not a solution.

Comment: I have not been able to find any configuration wherein `this` is anything but undefined.

Comment: Inside a React component's `render` method `this` is certainly not `undefined`. There is not much we can do without an example that reproduces the issue. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Dude the error says something completely different

Comment: The error has nothing to do with `this`. It means that either `this.refs[route]` (for some value of `route`) or `this.refs.root` doesn't exist. Add a debugger statement or pause on exception, inspect the variables and find out when you get `undefined`.

Comment: If right after the `if` conditional I hit a `debugger` and enter `this` it returns undefined.

Comment: `this` being `undefined` at runtime is a red herring! The code is transpiled to use `_this` instead of `this`. (`this.refs` is converted to `_this.refs`).  The error clearly shows that the problem is not with `this`.

Comment: `if (url.includes(route) && this.refs[route]) {`

Comment: `this.refs` should not be used inside `render`, in part because refs only exist after the first render. Your component likely needs some refactoring. Check out React's docs on [Don't Overuse Refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs).

Comment: @RossAllen, thank you, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

By assigning this to another variable and then accessing props using newly created variables works in render